# VBA Code that will subtract a number from the same row in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a sheet like this, it goes down for a lot of rows, but this is just a snippet. I want the user to input a value, call it "x" and in the first row starting from March I want to subtract the "x" from the value in March. If march the value in March goes to 0, I want to move on to February and subtract whatever amount is remaining in X from Feb. This keeps going until we hit January.

Stop either if x is 0 or if there is no more left to subtract from march, feb and jan. The Jan through march values cant go below 0. I have experience coding in python but I am unfamiliar with VBA syntax. My issue is getting the recursion aspect.

```
Sub variance_sub()

Dim reduce As Double

reduce = InputBox("what is the Variance required?")

If reduce = 0 Then

    MsgBox ("No further action required")

ElseIf reduce > 0 Then

    subtraction_factor = Range("T7").Value

    Range("T7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("T7").Value - reduce, 0)

    reduce = WorksheetFunction.Max(reduce - subtraction_factor, 0)

Else

    Range("T7").Value = Range("T7").Value + reduce

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough example? Maybe with numbers that are more reasonable for people to work with in their heads. Not sure you need to jump to the millions for an example where you want to reduce by 5. Can you show the starting point and then end point? Make sure to share the input that was used to get there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop is fine here - no recursion required:

```
Sub variance_sub()

    Dim reduce As Double, c As Range, diff As Double

    reduce = InputBox("what is the Variance required?")

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("T7") 'march cell

    If reduce = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No further action required"
    ElseIf reduce > 0 Then
        Do
            If c.Value >= reduce Then
                c.Value = c.Value - reduce
                reduce = 0
            Else
                diff = reduce - c.Value
                c.Value = 0
                reduce = diff
            End If
            If c.Column > 1 Then Set c = c.Offset(0, -1) 'move left if we can
        Loop While reduce > 0 And c.Column >= 18
    Else
        c.Value = c.Value + reduce
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me out!